# Regex to find string contained between HTML tags

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, regex, nsstring

My problem is finding the position of a specific word (ex: **span**) in an NSString containing html text, and replace this word.

For example, if my target word is **span**, my replacement text should look like:

```
<SPAN style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FF0000">span</SPAN>
```

If my starting text is:

```
<span class='i_04_12_000000'>this is a span</span>
```

My desired result would be:

```
<span class='i_04_12_000000'>this is a <SPAN style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FF0000">span</SPAN></span>
```

Obviously if I just search for **span** I won't find just the occurrence inside the html tag.
Ideas on how to locate the correct string, even with a NSRange ?

**UPDATE:**

This is the final solution: ;)

```
    +(NSString *)emphasizeString:(NSString *)stringToEmphasize inText:(NSString *)fullText
{
    NSString * regExp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(?i)([\\s\\.,>'-])(%@)([\\s\\.,;!\\?\\)<])",stringToEmphasize];;
    NSArray * regexResult = [fullText arrayOfCaptureComponentsMatchedByRegex:regExp];
    NSString * result = [NSString stringWithString:fullText];
    if([regexResult count] >0)
    {
        for (NSArray * match in regexResult)
        {

            NSString * all = [match objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString * before = [match objectAtIndex:1];
            NSString * matched = [match objectAtIndex:2];
            NSString * after = [match objectAtIndex:3];

            result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:all 
                                                       withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<SPAN style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FF0000\">%@</SPAN>%@",before, matched, after]
                                                          options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch 
                                                            range: [result rangeOfString:all]];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: example html string:  <span class='i_04_12_000000'>this is a span</span>  result:  <span class='i_04_12_000000'>this is a <SPAN style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FF0000\">span</SPAN>
</span>

Comment: are these specific words you're looking for surrounded by any kind of markup, e.g: `<span>`?

Comment: Better read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Kappe you should post your solution as an answer to your question. After two days, you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the final solution: ;)

```
    +(NSString *)emphasizeString:(NSString *)stringToEmphasize inText:(NSString *)fullText
{
    NSString * regExp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(?i)([\\s\\.,>'-])(%@)([\\s\\.,;!\\?\\)<])",stringToEmphasize];;
    NSArray * regexResult = [fullText arrayOfCaptureComponentsMatchedByRegex:regExp];
    NSString * result = [NSString stringWithString:fullText];
    if([regexResult count] >0)
    {
        for (NSArray * match in regexResult)
        {

            NSString * all = [match objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString * before = [match objectAtIndex:1];
            NSString * matched = [match objectAtIndex:2];
            NSString * after = [match objectAtIndex:3];

            result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:all 
                                                       withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<SPAN style=\"BACKGROUND-COLOR: #FF0000\">%@</SPAN>%@",before, matched, after]
                                                          options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch 
                                                            range: [result rangeOfString:all]];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex: `/<[a-z]+.*?>/`

EDIT: Update as per your new instructions:

Since the html tag preceding the text you want to capture has a variable number of characters, you can't use lookbehind to grab only the target word preceded by the opening tag. However, you could use:

`/(<)([a-z]+)(.*?>.*?)(\2)(.*?</\1>)/`

to capture an entire tag where the tag's name is repeated somewhere in its body text and isolate that piece of text in a capture group. Then, use a replacement method to with that regex as the search pattern, and `"$1$2$3<span style=\"background-color: #FF0000;\">$4</span>$5"` (where $4 indicates the fourth capture group containing our target text) for your replacement string.

Comment: This pattern will only locate `<span class='i_04_12_000000'>` and not the *span* between the tags.

Comment: @arcain Check my edited post to see if it's more along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Aaron, this regex don't seems work, i update the answer with my solution